# chartjs, no cross lines but horizontal line on the same level untill a next point

Tags: javascript, chart.js

So in the example below, the top chart is what is default being displayed, the points on the chart are connect by lines going from point to point.

I am looking for a way to have it like the bottom example
so a horizontal line from a point to the next point

[image: mock chart lines linear and stepped]

Answer (score 0):

Depending your dataset Checkout [this example](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/line/stepped.html)

Basically you just have to set the property `stepped` on the `dataset` object of a line chart.

**Here a short demo, showing the effect of this single property:**

```js
let data = [10, 20, 70, 30, 90]
new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: data,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Dataset',
        data: data,
        fill: false,
      },{
        label: 'Dataset(stepped) - offset by -100',
        data: data.map(v => v-100),
        fill: false,
        stepped: true,
      }]
    },
    options:{
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>    
<div class="chart" style="height:184px; width:350px;">
    <canvas  id="chart" ></canvas>
</div>
```